# How to pass javascript array variable values to html using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templating

I am new to [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/)

I want to create a table by populating values from a javascript array variable.
I created and entered values in my variable like this

```
        var result=[];    

        //some loop. Just demonstrating that there are multiple values of id and text
        result.push(
            {
                "id":obj["id"],                
                "text":obj["text"],
            }
        );
```

I want a new row for each id and text from result variable in html

```
<table>
<tr><td>id</td><td>text</td></tr>
<table>
```

What is way to do this using angular.js.

Comment: I am going to see if this helps http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Putting it here if anyone needs it.

**Javascript code:**

```
function controller($scope, $http) {

    $scope.results=[];
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

        $.each(data, function () {
            var obj = data;
            console.log(obj);
            $scope.results.push(
                {
                    "id": obj["obj_id"],                    
                    "text": obj["text"]
                }
            );


        });
    });


}
```

**html code**

```
<div  ng-controller="controller">
    <table ng-repeat="result in results">
    <tr><td>{{result.id}}</td><td>{{result.text}}</td></tr>
    <table>
</div>
```